# Manter click ativo em script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consegui executar um script onde ao fazer o mouseover(hover) em determinado objeto, o mesmo executa a ação desejada, mas eu gostaria de executar a ação com um click e eu nao estou conseguindo fazer nem com Javascript, nem JQuery...

```
<script>
        $('.dimmer_area').hover(function(){
            $('.dim_area').fadeIn(200);
        },function(){
            $('.dim_area').fadeOut(200);
        });
    </script>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Por favor, finalize a pergunta escolhendo uma das respostas, Não deixe a pergunta em aberto. ObG!

Answer (score 1):

Se está usando a mesma ação, pode usar `.fadeToggle(200)`, que é mais adequado para a situação, dentro de um evento `click`:

```js
$('.dimmer_area').click(function(){
   $('.dim_area').fadeToggle(200);
});
```

```css
.dimmer_area{
   width: 200px;
   height: 20px;
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dimmer_area">clique aqui</div>
<div class="dim_area">dim_area</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer com `click` basta adicionar uma variável para ajudar a controlar o estado, exemplo...

```js
let ativo = false;

$('.dimmer_area').click(function(){
            if(ativo)
            $('.dim_area').fadeIn(200);
            else
            $('.dim_area').fadeOut(200);
            
            ativo = !ativo;
        });
```

```css
.dimmer_area {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #424242;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.dim_area {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="dimmer_area">
  <div class="dim_area">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado @felipe-duarte ! Existe alguma maneira de fazer o hover e click juntos em um só script ? 
Estou usando os scripts em separado cada um e estou tendo dores de cabeça.
Se existir algum algoritmo, ficarei agradecido.

Comment: @EitaEhNOiz pode explicar melhor, não entendi kkk

Comment: Olá @felipe-duarte,  no script que vc criou, é possível fazer o hover e o click juntos ? 
Ao passar o mouse em cima de um determinado objeto, ele faz uma ação e clicando, ele mantem essa ação ativa.
É possível ?

Comment: basta duplicar a parte onde faço a ação do click para outra com o hover, ai ctz que dará certo pois a variável vai permitir o controle global...

Comment: ok, obrigado pela sugestao.